# XSD, different child nodes in XML 1.0

Tags: xml, xsd

The daughter element specification `<child>` should be forbidden with the parameter of the attribute "in" of `<parent>` element and authorized enabled with the parameter "out"

```
 valid
    { <parent type="in" name="one"> 
      </parent>

      <parent type="out" name="two"> 
       <child...>   
       </child>
      </parent>  } 



 invalid
    { <parent type="in" name="one">
       <child...>   {this element mustn't be here}
       </child>
      </parent>

      <parent type="out" name="two"> 
       <child...>   
       </child>
      </parent>  }
```

How can the given condition be realized in XSD?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So it seems you're trying to express a particular type of [co-occurance constraint](http://www.w3.org/wiki/Co-occurrence_constraints).  Namely that when `type="in"` then `child` is permitted.  When `type="out"` then `child` is not permitted.

I don't think you can do that at all with XSD.   You could define two different types (one for when `type="in"` and then the other.  You could then derive different elements, one which permitted child, the other which didn't, but you couldn't do both of those under the same element.

To do this sort of thing, you probably want [schematron](http://www.xml.com/pub/a/2003/11/12/schematron.html).   It permits writing more sophisticated rules, and gives you a pattern language that you can use to assert this rule.